# automate the call to constant defined variables/ macros

Tags: objective-c

apologies this query had to be pulled

Comment: please provide minimum example code of you problem

Comment: hey, you can edit your question instead of making this mess in comment

Comment: //configuration.h   
#define Config_1

#define Config_2

#define Config_3

//main.c  
#define Config_1

    #define Config_2

    #define Config_3 for(;;){
        //int fan, thermostat, heater, extractor;
        char temp;
        if(temp>=15){
            #define Config_1
        }
        if(temp<=15){
            #define Config_2
        }
        if(temp==15){
            #define Config_3
        }
        //i was wondering how to feed this random temp (temperature) and automate it to respond accordingly
    }

Comment: NoobScript: I did what sage444 asked: I put your comment in the question. You should have done that and not posted the code in a comment. Next time, just click the "edit" link below your question and edit the question.

Comment: FWIW, this is not how you use `#define`. You constantly redefine these macros as empty macros. That doesn't make sense at all. Why don't you tell us what you really want to achieve? Why can't you have three real functions that are called depending on the value of temp? Also, show us your real code, and not some kind of useless pseudo-code.